# How to check token address when receiving onERC1155Received

Tags: erc-1155

I have two contracts, contract A that implements IERC1155 and contract B that implements ERC1155Receiver.

When I receive the following onERC1155Received how to check that the token being transferred is indeed token A? Otherwise I want to reject it.

```
onERC1155Received(address operator, address from, uint256 id, uint256 value, bytes data)
```

I think the id can be the same between two contracts, so I need the address of the token to compare it with contract A's address.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit:

operator seems to be the origin, if you want to check the address of the ERC1155 contract that sent the tokens, check _msgSender().